# Why does strlen() in this instance return one less than the number I expected?

Tags: c, strcat

Example:

```
    {
        int a,b;
        char s1[]="ABCDEF";
        char s2[]="ZWXYZ";
        strcpy(s1,s2); 
        strcat(s1,"L#@");
        a=strlen(s1);
        b=strlen(s2);
        printf("%d%d",a,b);
    }
```

Returns 8 and 5. I expected strlen to return 9. I figure # or @ must be the culprit here. However, when I remove #, it returns 7, as if # was counted. So, it seems like strlen is returning what I expect but minus one. What is going on here?

Comment: You are writing past the end of `s1`. It's UB. No point making sense of it.

Comment: You have *undefined behavior*

Comment: The definition `char s1[]="ABCDEF";` is equal to `char s1[7]= { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', '\0' };`

Comment: Unlike other programming languages, C does not have a string type. It uses lower level character arrays. All memory allocation for them has to be done manually. Failing to grasp this is a classic mistake by people coming from other programming languages to C.

Comment: Even without the undefined behaviour, why do expect it to be 9? You replace the content of `s1` with `s2` which has a length of 5 and then append on the end an extra 3 characters.

Answer (score 5):

When you say

```
 strcat(s1,"L#@");
```

the concatenated string (the result) is too long to fit into `s1`. It runs out of the valid boundary and as a reuslt, you have [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to make sure that the result of the concatenation can be held into the target memory. In other words, you need to make sure that `s1` is large enough to hold the result of

```
      strcat(s1,"L#@");
```

A basic way of achieving this would be to make the target big enough by specifying the size at compile time, something like

```
#define SIZE 16
....
char s1[SIZE]="ABCDEF";
```

and the, use it accordingly.

here, we're just making the `s1` big enough to hold the result of the concatenation.

That said, the return type of `strlen()` is `size_t`, so you should use `%zu` to print the result!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. This was a question on my practice midterm. I suppose I'll see these type of questions on my actual midterm. How would I go about doing this question? Because the correct answer (according to my professor) is a = 8 and b = 5; not undefined behavior.

Comment: @LtLame If your professor actually said that he is dangerously incompetent (not only doesn't know things, but knows the wrong things and teaches them).

Comment: @LtLame it will be like that, provided you allocate enough memory.

Comment: @Art You cannot say that, probably the professor did not look at this code.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that you're writing past the end of the string....

After `strcpy(s1,s2)` s1 contains "ZWXYZ".

After `strcat(s1,"L#@")` s1 contains "ZWXYZL#@" which has length ogf 8